# Dependant drop down list in row instead columns

Tags: google-apps-script

Im using script which generates drop down list. The problem is it always generates next list in column on right. I want to change that to each choice generate a next dependant drop list in row below....

Here's script i'm using

```html
function depDrop_(range, sourceRange){
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange,true).build();
range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
function onEdit (){
var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
if (aColumn == 1 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
}
else if (aColumn == 2 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
}
else if (aColumn == 3 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with `getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1)`  Maybe your problem has something to do with `aColumn + 1`?  The beginning point is always the active cell.  Remove the `+ 1` from `aColumn + 1` and add 1 to the row.

Comment: "Remove the + 1 from aColumn + 1 and add 1 to the row." How to do that ??

Comment: Use the mouse pointer and put the cursor where the `+ 1` is and then hit the delete key until it the `+ 1` is gone.  Then save your changes.